# what does request.getHeader("host") return when multiple legs are configured

Tags: java, dns, csrf, servlet-filters, request-headers

In order to implement CSRF security in Restful services, I followed the documentation in OWASP

OWASP is suggesting below approach to handle CSRF attacks (ref URL: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

There are two steps that we need to follow:
1.  Check standard headers to verify the request is same origin 
2.  AND Check CSRF token

**1.    Check standard headers to verify the request is same origin:**
It was suggested to check the host against referrer. As it is not easy to change referer  and host headers in request, checking if Referer Contains Host or not is the first check we can do and I have taken care of it.

**2.    Check CSRF Token**

Checking Synchronized token is one way to achieve it. But it works out for stateful application. As our application is Stateless, It was suggested by OWASP to pass a custom header and check for its presence in Server side and I implemented the same.

I tried to write below code to check first point

```
 String host = "/"+request.getHeader("host")+"/";
 String referer = request.getHeader("referer");

if(referer!=null && !referer.contains(host)){
            LOGGER.info("referer doesnot contain host");
            accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, new AccessDeniedException(
                    "Missing or non-matching CSRF-token"));
            return;
        }
```

This worked properly in my local and test env where only one leg is there. But when I tested it in stage env which has two legs, Referer and host names are different.

host name is having the machine name like

```
machin002:8080
```

but I am expecting domain name like

```
sample.domain.com
```

Do I need to configure the domain name for this host?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your referrer check is weak.

Say the host header is `www.example.com` for a legitimate request.

If an attacker sends you a cross-origin request from their own domain `evil.example.org`, then can pass your check by sending the request from this URL: `https://evil.example.org/?www.example.com`.

The vulnerable code is

```
referer.contains(host)
```

Referer will be `https://evil.example.org/?www.example.com`, which you can see contains `www.example.com`.

Referer checking is a weaker form of CSRF protection because of parsing bugs like this, and sometimes users disable referer in their browser for privacy purposes.

Therefore, you should check both `Origin` and `Referer`, however the former has [its own problems](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91190/8340). If you don't care about protecting old browsers, then this is  a good CSRF mitigation. Old browsers are likely to have other bugs too that make them insecure, so you could argue that a user using an old browser is insecure anyway.

> our application is Stateless

This puts into question why you need CSRF in the first place?

> Do I need to configure the domain name for this host?

It sounds like you need a configuration variable where you can set the expected host you are receiving in the `referer` and `origin` headers.